# How to trace and analyze FreeRTOS tasks on CCS (Code Composer Studio) 9

Tags: task, freertos, code-composer

I inherited a Texas TIVA TM4C-based FreeRTOS multi-thread project. It's the first time for me managing such multi-task environment, I've only experienced single-thread programming with no OS.
I'm in the need of debugging some strange behaviour in my application when debug session comes to FreeRTOS suspend function, i.e. I need to know which task is running, for how much time, which other task preempts it, and so on.
In my debug perspective (CCS is based on Eclipse) I don't even see the task list.
My debugger is the Segger J-Link.
Any hint to get me started will be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few FreeRTOS kernel aware debuggers around, including plug-ins for Eclipse, but I'm not sure if any will work with the Eclipse based CCS as they may require GDB.  As you have a J-link you could probably use Segger Ozone to open the elf file created by CCS and use that.  You always have the trace too option which is not compiler dependent: http://www.freertos.org/trace

Answer (score 0):

Even when accepted answer was posted, Segger had provided RTOS plugin for thread-awareness in Eclipse.

Activate it on any eclipse-based IDEs in your "GDB SEGGER J-Link Debugging"->Debugger settings in field "Other options" adding "-rtos GDBServer/RTOSPlugin_FreeRTOS"

[Here's a post from 2018 how to set it up](https://dzone.com/articles/show-freertos-threads-in-eclipse-debug-view-with-s)

For more detailed views you can even have [fancy GUI by Segger](https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/systemview/) with forum posts dating back as far as 2016